# Unable to fit all the rows horizontally in a TableLayout in Android programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am creating a TableLayout to populate data dynamically. The problem I am facing here is that rows are not fitting horizontally into the screen.
This is my desired View,

```
\-----------------------------------------------------\
\|   Student Name    | Q1 | Q2 | Q3  | Total | % |\
\-----------------------------------------------------\
```

But the problem is,as Student Name is quite a large row (in width), the other rows are not fitting into the screen, 
they are appearing like as shown below, from Q4 onwards all the rows are not fitting into the screen.

```
\------------------------------------\---------------- 
\|   Student Name    | Q1 | Q2 | Q3  \| Total | % |
\------------------------------------\----------------
```

[image: Student Report table]

This is the code I have used to create this view dynamically

students_table.xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/maintable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

QuestionPaperChecking.java

```
 /** Table Row - Header */
    trHeader = new TableRow(mContext);
    trHeader.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    /* Student name */
    TextView tvStudentName = new TextView(mContext);
    tvStudentName.setText("Student Name");
    tvStudentName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tvStudentName.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    tvStudentName.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    tvStudentName.setBackgroundColor(getColor(mContext, R.color.background_blue_light));
    tvStudentName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvStudentName.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    trHeader.addView(tvStudentName);

    /* Question 1 */
    TextView tvQ1 = new TextView(mContext);
    tvQ1.setText("Q1");
    tvQ1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tvQ1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
    tvQ1.setBackgroundColor(getColor(mContext, R.color.background_blue_light));
    tvQ1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvQ1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    tvQ1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    trHeader.addView(tvQ1);

    //Similarly I have created all other rows

    // Add the TableRow Header to the TableLayout
    tblBattingSide.addView(trHeader, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Note: stretchColumns & shrinkColumns didnot work

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What have you tried?

Comment: @CurlyCorvus as mentioned above, I am trying to create a TableLayout to add data dynamically, my problem is it is not fitting in the screen and some of the rows are going out of the screen. I want to fit them in with `Student Name` getting  a wider width.

Comment: Have you tried stacking Q1-4 in a vertical line?

Comment: I also believe you'd want the scrollview to match_parent(identical to fill_parent) and the inner linearlayout to wrap_content

Comment: @CurlyCorvus, yes, replaced warp_content in scrollView with fill_parent width and fill_parent in table_layout with wrap_content. Also added stretchColumns="*" to the tableLayout. It worked, thanks :)

Comment: @CurlyCorvus, sry but it did not work when I added some extra text in the Student's name section (see above pic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you'd want to the text on the student's name to wrap to the next line.

The first thing to fix is the `layout_width`. Set the `layout_width` value of the `ScrollView` to `match_parent`/`fill_parent`. Do the same for the header `TableRow` (`trHeader`) as well as for each row you had to the table. Just to be clear, `layout_width` on the `TableLayout` itself should remain `match_parent`/`fill_parent`.

What this does is make sure all these views fit width-wise into the parents. This will still not completely solve the problem since the views in the rows still "push" the columns beyond the width of the table's container.

The second step is to set `shrinkColumns` on the `TableLayout` to `"1"`. This will shrink the first column as much as possible until the table fits in the screen (or its container), and the text will wrap. Alternatively, you can set it to `"*"` if you want all columns to shrink.

Comment: Thnx @CurlyCovus :) your suggestions worked, though I had to make some changes to it ( I have edited your answer, please review it).